# Unsigned int C++ portability

Tags: c++, coding-style, int

Is there a shortened label typedef defined for 'unsiged integer' that works across most/all platforms? I see uint or UINT alot in Windows, but understand this is not consistently implemented on other platforms. I'm happy to type 'unsigned int' for every instance, but if there's a standard typedef (like 'uint', although that's not consistently implemented), I'll use it. I suspect this is not the case after doing a bit of research, but people may have some knowledge of eg. C++11 etc., or standard headers across *nix/Windows that implement the same label. I'm not much interested in strictly specifying the bit size of unsigned int: it's used for low iteration loops only.

Comment: `unsigned int` is a standard, built-in type that you can use on every C++ platform. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: you dont really have to worry about portability when using built in types (unless you are building app for embedded systems or something alike). They will work the same way, unless you want to use some kind of networking - send data between different architectures?

Comment: And unless you are using printf format specifiers like "ld", "lld" and so on and try to compile on 32-bit and 64-bit. So I will also go for uint32_t and similar.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715862/safe-assumption-regarding-size-and-alignment-of-datatypes-on-different-platforms/18716620

Comment: @kerrek SB - the desire was to use whatever is used most consistently ie. if people use a shortcut. I'll stick with the more verbose, but clear 'unsigned int'. Given the question has got 3 downvotes for being 'opinion based'  I've reworded it, but thanks to the people who did reply.

Answer (score 2):

The abbreviation of `unsigned int` is `unsigned`. Similarly, `long int` can be shortened to `long`, and `unsigned long int` can be shortened to `unsigned long`.

There's one exception to this rule : `signed char` nor `unsigned char` can be shortened to `char`.

Comment: That's interesting MSalters, I had no idea those abbreviations were in C.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, type sizes are defined by the compiler that you're using and the platform that your target program (the executable) will run on.

For example, on an x86 machine, almost all compilers will take `int` (and hence `unsigned int`) to mean a standard 32-bit integer. However, on a hypothetical 128-bit CPU, `int` will probably refer to a 64-bit or 128-bit integer.

However, if you are like me and insist on knowing what the size of your integer is at all times, I suggest you check out the `cstdint` header, which was introduced in C++11.

This allows you to specify integers of particular sizes (e.g. `uint32_t`) independently of the compiler and platform. Beware though, if a particular platform doesn't support that size, your program will either not compile.

Check out this site for more details: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/
Use `#include <stdint.h>` for C and `#include <cstdint>` for C++.

Comment: -1 “[…] or it will be scaled down to the largest integer possible.” is nonsense.

Comment: So it throws a compile-time error?

Comment: You will get *uint32_t': identifier not found* errors.

Comment: I think the answer is ok, you just need to remove the "scaled down" part.

Comment: Done. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Thanks cjdb1. I'm not interested in the size of the integer in this case: the unsigned int is merely used for low-ish iteration loops (<20).

Comment: In that case, just use compiler inference. `auto` is a brilliant thing (requires that you compile with C++0x/C++11).

Answer (score 1):

The language standard and standard library do not define any "trivial" aliases for types which would serve no purpose other than providing an alternative name.

The standard library does define several type aliases with platform-dependent meaning. For example, the integral type `std::uintptr_t` is an integral type large enough to represent any object pointer value; `std::max_align_t` is a type whose `alignof`-value is the largest the platform provides. Other type aliases are the conditionally defined `std::uint32_t` etc, which, if they exist, are integral types of a fixed width with two's complement representation. Naturally those are just typedefs of one of the fundamental types, but the meaning is different, and none of those are trivial, and so there is a good reason to have those typedefs.

Comment: Thanks Kerrek, I'll stick with 'unsigned int'. I didn't think the question showed that much 'lack of research' but SO's pedantists keep downvoting it. We're down to -4 now so I expect others to jump on bandwagon which what they usually do when this happens, so I'm about to delete the question all together!